# upgrader: ^8.1.0 package can I get the app store or play store live version? and can I use this package without the app casting file?

Tags: flutter, dart

The upgrader package, version ^8.1.0, is typically used for managing app updates within Flutter applications. It allows you to notify users about available updates and facilitate the update process within the app. However, it doesn't directly provide access to the live versions of your app on the App Store or Google Play Store.To find the live version of your app on the App Store (for iOS) or Google Play Store (for Android), you should visit the respective stores and search for your app using its name. Users can download and install your app from there.